# How do I use OData4J with an unknown number of child objects?

Tags: odata4j

I am trying to build a `createEntity` OEntity for an object that has multiple child collections within it.

I have looked over many of the example projects, but they all seem to assume that you have a known number of child objects in a collection so that you can use .`inLine(“ObjectName”,  ObjectOEntity1, ObjecteOEntity2…)`

I have tried looking at the documentation and have not identified anything that leads me to think I can create a collection of OEntity objects that can then be added to my parent object with the inline.

The closest I found was the example listed on:

http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/browse/odata4j-fit/src/test/java/org/odata4j/producer/jpa/northwind/test/CreateTest.java?name=0.6

Has anyone else run into this problem?
If so how did you get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in an array of `OEntity` objects. The core4j library that is used by odata4j contains some helper methods that can - for example - be used to get an array from an `Iterable`:

```
OEntity[] entitiesArray = Enumerable.create(entitiesIterable)
    .toArray(OEntity.class);
```

But as there are also two variants of the properties method...

```
OCreateRequest<T> properties(OProperty<?>... props);
OCreateRequest<T> properties(Iterable<OProperty<?>> props);
```

... it might make sense to add an `inline` method that directly takes an `Iterable<OEntity>`.

Comment: Thank you.  I will take a look at that.  On the `inLine` method that takes the `Iterable<OEntity>` is what I was expecting to see but could not find.

Comment: @ewjames - I have added this second `inline` method to the odata4j codebase: <https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/detail?r=5119db96f2f63f842ba92b695e11ed13de7a5acb>

Comment: Thank you I will test this out next week, i am on a different project at the moment.